# Which statement regarding Lipschitz conditions is stronger?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Statement 1:

A function $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition in the rectangular region $D$ if there is a positive real number $L$ such that
$$|f(t, u) - f(t, v)| \leq L|u - v|$$
for all $(t,u) \in D$ and $(t, v) \in D$.

Statement 2:

There is a finite, positive, real number $L$ such that
$$|\frac{d}{dy}f(t, y)| \leq L$$
for all $(t,y) \in D$.

Is this statement stronger than (i.e., more restrictive then), equivalent to or weaker than (i.e., less restrictive than) statement 1? Justify your answer.

My view:

I would say the statements are equivalent the max 'slope' for any two points in statement 1 won't exceed the max slope in statement 2.

Comment: You can have a Lipschitz function not differentiable in one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement 2 is stronger than Statement 1.

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(t,u):=g(t)h(u),\text{ for all }(t,u)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}
$$
where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz. Then, $f$ satisfies the Statement 1 everywhere, whereas Statement 2 is satisfied only upto almost evereywhere (Rademacher Theorem).